# Terminate istio sidecar istio-proxy for a kubernetes job / cronjob

Tags: kubernetes, istio

We recently started using istio [Istio](https://istio.io) to establish a service-mesh within out [Kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io) landscape.

We now have the problem that jobs and cronjobs do not terminate and keep running forever if we inject the istio `istio-proxy` sidecar container into them. The `istio-proxy` should be injected though to establish proper mTLS connections to the services the job needs to talk to and comply with our security regulations.

I also noticed the open issues within Istio ([istio/issues/6324](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/6324)) and kubernetes ([kubernetes/issues/25908](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/25908)), but both do not seem to provide a valid solution anytime soon.

At first a pre-stop hook seemed suitable to solve this issue, but there is some confusion about this conecpt itself: [kubernetes/issues/55807](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/55807)

```
lifecycle:
  preStop:
    exec:
      command: 
        ...
```

Bottomline: Those hooks will not be executed if the the container successfully completed.

There are also some relatively new projects on GitHub trying to solve this with a dedicated controller (which I think is the most preferrable approach), but to our team they do not feel mature enough to put them right away into production:

- [k8s-controller-sidecars](https://github.com/nrmitchi/k8s-controller-sidecars)
- [K8S-job-sidecar-terminator](https://github.com/cropse/K8S-job-sidecar-terminator)

In the meantime, we ourselves ended up with the following workaround that execs into the sidecar and sends a `SIGTERM` signal, but only if the main container finished successfully:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: terminate-sidecar-example-service-account
---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: terminate-sidecar-example-role
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["pods"]
    verbs: ["get","delete"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["pods/exec"]
    verbs: ["create"]
---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: terminate-sidecar-example-rolebinding
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: terminate-sidecar-example-service-account
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: terminate-sidecar-example-role
---
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: terminate-sidecar-example-cronjob
  labels:
    app: terminate-sidecar-example
spec:
  schedule: "30 2 * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: terminate-sidecar-example
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: terminate-sidecar-example
          annotations:
            sidecar.istio.io/inject: "true"
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: terminate-sidecar-example-service-account
          containers:
          - name: ****
            image: ****
            command:
              - "/bin/ash"
              - "-c"
            args:
              - node index.js && kubectl exec -n ${POD_NAMESPACE} ${POD_NAME} -c istio-proxy -- bash -c "sleep 5 && /bin/kill -s TERM 1 &"
            env:
              - name: POD_NAME
                valueFrom:
                  fieldRef:
                    fieldPath: metadata.name
              - name: POD_NAMESPACE
                valueFrom:
                  fieldRef:
                    fieldPath: metadata.namespace
```

So, the ultimate question to all of you is: **Do you know of any better workaround, solution, controller, ... that would be less hacky / more suitable to terminate the `istio-proxy` container once the main container finished its work?**

Comment: There's a open issue https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/6324.

Answer (score 23):

```
- command:
  - /bin/sh
  - -c
  - |
    until curl -fsI http://localhost:15021/healthz/ready; do echo \"Waiting for Sidecar...\"; sleep 3; done;
    echo \"Sidecar available. Running the command...\";
    <YOUR_COMMAND>;
    x=$(echo $?); curl -fsI -X POST http://localhost:15020/quitquitquit && exit $x
```

**Update:** sleep loop can be omitted if `holdApplicationUntilProxyStarts` is set to `true` (globally or as an annotation) starting with [istio 1.7](https://istio.io/latest/news/releases/1.7.x/announcing-1.7/change-notes/)

Answer (score 10):

For those for whom curl is a luxury my wget version of the [Dimitri's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65719287):

```
command:
  - /bin/sh
  - -c
  - |
    until wget -q --spider http://127.0.0.1:15021/healthz/ready 2>/dev/null; do echo "Waiting for Istio sidecar..."; sleep 3; done;
    echo \"Sidecar available. Running...\";
    <COMMAND>;
    x=$?; wget -q --post-data='' -S -O /dev/null http://127.0.0.1:15020/quitquitquit && exit $x
```

For those who can't even afford wget, use bash:

```
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/15020
echo -e "POST /quitquitquit HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 127.0.0.1\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n" >&3
cat <&3
```

Answer (score 5):

I have found a work around by editing the configmap of istio-sidecar-injector as per the link Istio documentation

https://istio.io/docs/setup/additional-setup/sidecar-injection/

`apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: istio-sidecar-injector
data:
  config: |-
    policy: enabled
    neverInjectSelector:
      - matchExpressions:
        - {key: job-name, operator: Exists}`

But with this changes in our cronjob sidecar will not inject and istio policy will not apply on the cronjob job, and in our case we dont want any policy to be enforced by istio

Note :- job-name is by default label gets added in the pod creation

Answer (score 4):

This was not a misconfiguration, this was a bug in upstream Kubernetes. As of September of 2019, this [has been resolved](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/6324#issuecomment-533923427) by Istio by introducing a `/quitquitquit` endpoint to the Pilot agent.

Unfortunately, Kubernetes has [not been so steadfast](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/65502) in solving this issue themselves. So it still does exist in some facets. However, the `/quitquitquit` endpoint in Istio should have resolved the problem for this specific use case.