# Cronjob with sidecar logging container no exit code

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob, sidecar

Cronjob needs exit code to make the job successful or failed but with sidecar container an example the log container keep running and there is no exit code, even the job of the main container might run successfully the final state remain failed. There is any way to mitigate that issue ?! Thanks

Comment: Wait... log container... are you running a rsyslog/syslog sidecar? Sounds wrong... Can you share your CronJob definition?

Comment: There is a [long-standing Kubernetes issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/25908) about this.  If the sidecar is specifically Istio's proxy, [Terminate istio sidecar istio-proxy for a kubernetes job / cronjob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54921054/terminate-istio-sidecar-istio-proxy-for-a-kubernetes-job-cronjob) discusses Istio-specific solutions for it.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze this is what exactly I'm looking for.

Comment: @DavidMaze could you possibly post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Having analyzed the comments it looks like it's [a know issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/25908) and the fix can be found [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54921054/terminate-istio-sidecar-istio-proxy-for-a-kubernetes-job-cronjob).